# Paypal: Can i return a receipt no or order no when going back to "return" URL?

Tags: php, html, paypal

I would like to be able to launch a payment success page within my application after a Paypal transaction. As part of this, i would like to display a receipt number on the screen for user's reference (and to store in a database)

Currently, my code looks like this:

**Form**

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://myurl/success.php">`

**Inside Success.php**

```
<script>
    alert(/*receipt no*/);
</script>
```

At the moment, its purpose is to simply alert a receipt no. I am hoping i can change it to something like this:

```
"alert(<?php echo $_GET['receipt_no'] ?>)"
```

Is there a way i can tell Paypal that i would like it to send back a receipt number to me? And can it be accessible via URL variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use custom field

```
<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='your receiptnumber'>
```

and it will posted back to your return url..as well as to your notify url you can access $_POST['custom']

you can also use

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='receipt number'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='receipt number'>
```

but that will be displayed to the user in paypal site..

you can use txn_id for tracking records, it is returned by paypal. store it in your database

**What I do**

**I store everything to the database.. as well as write it to a file.**

**PDT vs IPN**

**PDT**

- 1)Variables are returned to return url. For this to work the user has to click on return to merchant(or something) to return to your website. or you have to set it in paypal to automatically to return to your website after paying.**If you have not set paypal to return automatically or the user doesn't click on return to merchant or if there is any problem in your return url code than you have no way of knowing that the user paid.**
- 2)And there is no way that the variables are coming from paypal, because anybody can create a form with method post with all the required variables and send it to your return url.

**IPN**

- 1) Variables are returned to notify url. Works in the background, after sending the variables paypal will wait for 200 ok message( that is it will check whether you have successfully received the variables) if not it will resend the message(as per the document).
- 2) For security-- you should send all the variables return to you by ipn back to paypal. paypal will check whether it sends it. If the variables are sent by paypal than paypal will send the message verified. so you can be sure that the variables are actually sent by paypal..

for more info https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/

and most important even if you use ipn you need to use https, otherwise somebody can perform man-middle-attack.( hackers can sit in the middle and respond istead of paypal for verification and etc)

for more info https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: would this be a receipt number paypal generates or one i define myself? Or can i generate a receipt number that paypal will store in its records?

Comment: custom field is what you send it to paypal, and that will be returned as it is.. it is not generated by paypal.. you need to create and send it paypal..

Comment: @Notaras you can use txn_id for tracking records, it is returned by paypal. store it in your database

Comment: since I can't explain it in comment I updated my post..please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

As v Sugumar as pointed out, you *can* do it. The question is *should* you did it. You might be better off generating your receipt number at your own end, either before or after you send the user to PayPal, and storing it in a database or session variable.

Using a Javascript alert to show a receipt number (and moreover using PHP to write Javascript variables) is also a bit 'ewww yuck' from a code standards perspective. Why not generate a proper receipt in PHP and just display it at the success.php page?

As Naval Dabral mentions, it's trivial to store data in $_SESSION. However you'd need to do something more like (because you wouldn't be using PayPal's GET variables):

```
 <?php
   //Before user is sent to PayPal.
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['receipt'] = "receipt number"
 ?>
```

User pays and is returned to success.php

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   echo "Thank you for your order. Your Receipt number is " . $_SESSION['receipt'];
 ?>
```

It would also mitigate against someone guessing a receipt number and gaining access to your user's sales details, as the receipt would be stored in a secure PHP session, rather than an insecure and guessable GET variable.

Comment: dont mind the alert echo thing. That will be replaced later on. The trouble with self-generating a receipt number is that this has no relation to the one that Paypal generates. And if in future there is ever a need to console the transaction recorded in my database with one in Paypal's records, it cannot be done. Since yesterday i have delved a bit deeper and discovered that Paypal's "PDT" has the right thing i am looking for

Comment: "PDT" is problematic ipn is best

Comment: You might also want to go further and investigate Stripe ;-). That's what I did a few years ago and it was like emerging from a persistent migraine. Appreciate that's simply opinion and not strictly relevant, but just an idea if you haven't considered it. Apologies to developers who love PayPal's various APIs.

Comment: Also ... as I understand it, PayPal will generate it's own receipt regardless of any receipt number you might pass it. You can't replace their own reference system. But anyway ... sounds like you've found a solution.

Comment: @vSugumar what is problematic about PDT?

Answer (score 0):

store receipt no in session like this

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $receipt_no=$_GET['receipt_no'];

    $_SESSION["receipt_session"]=$receipt_no

?>
```

and you can use this value when payment